# I'm not able to upload ipa file to apple store. Any suggestions?

Tags: ios, react-native-ios, ipa

I've uploaded non-Xcode builds with xcrun altool --upload-app -f path-to-build.ipa -u your-account@apple.com. It won't show any progress, but you can see the network traffic in Activity Monitor. It finishes with No errors uploading 'path-to-build.ipa'.

Comment: There might be some issues in your build like which is related to capabilities, etc. Check the your mail associated with apple account, Apple will mail you regarding this  if this is the issues.

Answer (score 0):

While we are using xcrun commands to upload app, it will not show any progress and if you are getting this "No errors uploading 'path-to-build.ipa'.", it means your iPad is uploaded successfully, so please check your developer account for the application you will see uploaded builds.